# fix an ordering of the edges in an undirected networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

In an undirected NetworkX graph edges are represented as Python tuples. their ordering depends on the way you ask for them. Here is a small example what I'm referring to:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.complete_bipartite_graph(2,2)
print(g.edges())
print(g.edges(2))
```

The output is

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Is there a way (not involving manual sorting) to avoid having different representation for an edge?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want since in the title you ask for ordered edges but in your example you ask for ordered nodes in the edges. In my examples I show ordering for both. Note that I use list comprehension to create new lists of edges -- the original list of edges (`some_edges`) is unchanged.

First how to sort individual tuples of nodes in a list of edges. That is, edges are in the same order but the nodes in them are sorted.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([
    (5, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 2)
])
some_edges = g.edges(2)
print("Not sorted:  ", some_edges)

print("SORTED")
# sort nodes in edges
some_edges_1 = [tuple(sorted(edge)) for edge in some_edges]
print("Sorted nodes:", some_edges_1)
```

And now how to sort edges in a list of edges.

```
# sort edges in list of edges
some_edges_2 = sorted(some_edges_1)
print("Sorted edges:", some_edges_2)
```

Output for both blocks of code above:

```
Not sorted:   [(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
SORTED
Sorted nodes: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
Sorted edges: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Here's also an example of reverse sorting where you can actually see the difference between sorting individual edges and sorting a list of edges.

```
print("Not sorted:  ", some_edges)
print("SORTED REVERSE")
# sort nodes in edges
some_edges_1 = [tuple(sorted(edge, reverse=True)) for edge in some_edges]
print("Sorted nodes:", some_edges_1)
# sort edges in list of edges
some_edges_2 = sorted(some_edges_1, reverse=True)
print("Sorted edges:", some_edges_2)
```

Output:

```
Not sorted:   [(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
SORTED REVERSE
Sorted nodes: [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
Sorted edges: [(5, 2), (4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1)]
```